# How to make Nipple.js Joystick responsive?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, responsive, joystick

I am currently using the javascript library **nipple.js** to add a joystick element to my **vue.js**-website.
The joystick is placed inside a **resizeable parent-element** but is of static size itself.
I was wondering how it would be possible to make the joystick element resize with its parent so it would have a fitting size when resizing the parent but also on different screen sizes in general.

This is how I initialize my Joystick in Vue right now

```
const options = {
      zone: this.$refs.nippleRef,
      mode: 'static',
      position: { left: '25%', top: '50%' },
      dynamicPage: true, // needed because of vue
      size: 150,
      restOpacity: 0.75,
    };
```

I tried using e.g. a percentage in the place of the 150 at the size value. However only numbers are valid there.

**I was wondering if there is a way to make the Joystick responsive either through javascript or with css?**

And this is the template part of the vue file btw:

```
<v-col>
 <div>
   <div ref="nippleRef"></div>
 </div>
</v-col>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get any where with this?  I was just trying to figure this out and came across your question.

Comment: I did not investigate for too long after as I moved on to work on sth else. Still this would be an issue for me and I would be eager to find out how to fix this. Have you found any additional information on this until now?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made it responsive, in the `static` mode, I added this to my css, make sure you adjust the margins on the front classe to 25% of the size you defined, the example below consider the size of 100px :

```css
.nipple {
    position: fixed !important;
}

.back {
    position: fixed !important;
}

.front {
    position: fixed !important;
    margin-left: -25px !important;
    margin-top: -25px !important;
    left: unset !important;
    top: unset !important;
}
```